# zend subquery is not working

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

I am using zend expression in my query.
This is my query.

```
    $oResultSet = $this->select(function (Select $select) use ($aWhere, $sGroup) {
        $select->columns(array('next_level_name' => new Expression("SELECT level_title from mry_game_sublevel WHERE sub_level = mry_game_sublevel.next_level LIMIT 1")));

        //$select->columns(array('count' => new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression('COUNT(*)')));

        $select ->join(
            'mry_game_main_level',
            'mry_game_sublevel.main_level_id = mry_game_main_level.main_level_id' ,
            array('main_level','level_name'),
            $select::JOIN_LEFT
        );
        if ($aWhere) {
            foreach ($aWhere as $key => $value) {
                $select->where($key.$value);
            }
        }
        if ($sGroup) {
            $select->group($sGroup);
        }          
    });

    return ! $oResultSet ? false : $oResultSet->toArray();
```

But I got an error message for this.

My mysql query is like this

```
select ee.main_level_id, 
(select sub_level from mry_game_sublevel where next_unlock = ee.sub_level) as dddd
from mry_game_sublevel as ee where ee.sub_level = 1.2
```

The error message:

> Statement could not be executed (42000 - 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT level_title from mry_game_sublevel WHERE sub_level = mry_game_sublevel.ne' at line 1)

Does anyone know what is the issue?

Comment: What error message did you get?

Comment: Statement could not be executed (42000 - 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT level_title from mry_game_sublevel WHERE sub_level = mry_game_sublevel.ne' at line 1)